# dwmblocks not reading $PATH

Tags: arch-linux, path, dwm, xinit

I'm using `archlinux`, `dwm` and `dwmblocks`. At startup `dwmblocks` shows only the icons of the blocks', without loading the scripts output. If I run

```
$ killall dwmblocks
```

and restart

```
$ dwmblocks &
```

it loads all required modules flawlessly.

For me, as a nonprofessional, it seems that the `$PATH` is not read *before* `startx`. So in `.xinitrc` I've sourced the `bashrc` (where the $PATH is extended) with

```
source $HOME/.bashrc &
```

before running `dwmblocks &`.

Also I've tried to delay the execution of `dwmblocks` by placing `sleep 2` a line above. This doesn't help either.

Searching for the `Xorg` log-files wasn't a success eather. I've found them as indicated by [`archwiki`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Session_log_redirection), however the file dowsen't seem to give any clue about `dwmblocks`.

Comment: Why are you setting the path in `.bashrc` [instead of `.profile`](https://superuser.com/a/183980/151431)? That's probably the problem. Does it work as expected if you put your PATH definitions in `~/.profile`, then log out and log back in? Also, how are you starting `dwmblocks`?

Comment: @terdon thank you for helping. I've added the paths to `.profile`. It didn't work. I'm starting`dwmblocks` in `.xinitrc` with `dwmblocks &` command.

Comment: Hmm. OK, I'm not sure that `.xinitrc` is read by bash, so `source` (which is a non=-portable, bash thing) might not be working. Try using `. /home/alex/.bashrc` (use `.` instead of `source` and use the full path) in your .xinitrc, does that help?

Comment: @terdon Thank you for the good advice. With `. /home/alex/.profile &` in `.xinitrc` it worked -- `source ...` doesen't work (do you have an idea why).  Please feel free to add it as answer and I will confirm and upvote it happily (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `source` is not portable. That is a bash-specific (possibly also some other shells) alias to the standard POSIX shell command `.`. So, it looks like your `.profile` is being read by something other than `bash` which means you should use `.` and not `source`.

Also, you can't be sure that `$HOME` will be set (it may well be in this case, but it might not) so use an absolute path instead, to be on the safe side. Finally, you don't need to send that to the background, it will just read the file and exit. Putting all that together, try using this instead:

```
. /home/alex/.bashrc
```

Also note that environment variables are better placed in `~/.profile` and not `~/.bashrc` since `~/.bashrc` is only read by the `bash` shell and only for interactive, non-login shell sessions.